# AnyLogic: last parameter arrival date is not specified

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have 3.523 incoming agents in my model. Model (and input through source) works perfectly fine, but always the last incoming agent is a problem.

[image: source-Block]

As seen in the picture, 3.522 agents came through. The last agent throws the following exception.

[image: exception and database]

If I deleted the last incoming agent out of the shown database, the agent 3.522 would throw the same exception. So why is there always a problem with the last incoming agent? Rest works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Weird. What if you delete a lot more entries? What if only 1 entry? Does it still occur? If not, find out the cutoff point, then it is model-related. Also make sure to import sorted data into the table only (sorted by date). The source block assumes entries are sorted by date!

Comment: Okay I have tried it: actually with only a few entrances there is no such problem. The entries in the original input table were already sorted. Do you think it has smth to do with the empty rows in the picture above? I don't know what the problem could be. This is the first time that problem occurred. And in my opinion this is not a logical problem of my model, right? As I said, the model works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like you have a lot of empty rows... this occurs often when you import from an Excel file.. make sure you erase some of the rows that come after the last data row in the excel file.

If you are not importing from Excel, then just erase the last rows from the database that have no data

Comment: Fair point. In Excel, make it a habit to always delete the last few rows below your last actual row, sometimes some data remnants linger and are interpreted as stuff by AnyLogic.